# Mobile widths headings breaks the horizontal layout

Tags: html, css

After a 30 minutes searching in Stack Overflow i could not find a solution to my problem, so here is it:

I have a static blog, and it's almost 99% responsive. The problem comes with a larger titles with wider words (like "documentfragments", in my case), they make a horizontal scrollbar in screens with a width below 400px.

Here the example:

[image]

As you can see, the width is (in that specific case), 320px and the header breaks the layout.

Im not a specialist in stylesheets, i'm learning but whatever i do (adjust the width, font size, etc) i cant give a solution to the problem.

Any idea?

Comment: Try using % for font size instead of pixels. Also, using media queries, keep adjusting the font-size.

Comment: share a demo code with "Jsfiddle" or "Code pen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here.

**1. Make the font-size smaller.**

You could reduce the font-size to something that is not likely to result in overflowing text.

**2. Hyphen-Wrap your words**

Using CSS you can set your element to hyphenate your words so they wrap when they run out of space. Just add `word-wrap: break-word` to the element in your css.

**3. Use Javascript**

You could write some javascript that calculates the width that it needs to fit into, then alter the font-size appropriately.

Comment: 2. Hypen-wrap the words. The solution

Comment: I'd say 1 and 2 together is the best solution. I prefer to just use hyphen wrapping as a backup for the rare really long word(like the one in your exmple). But I would keep the text small enough that you could easily fit a 10 char word on one line.